# Delete whitespace in each begin of line of file, using bash

Tags: linux, bash, whitespace, removing-whitespace

How i can delete whitespace in each line of file, using bash
For instance, file1.txt. Before:

```
  gg g
 gg g
t  ttt
```

after:

```
gg g
gg g
t  ttt
```

Comment: All whitespace or just leading whitespace characters on a line.  For instance, should "  ggg gg" become "ggg gg" or "ggggg"

Comment: 2 khachik Yes, whitespace is deleted, but how i can change my file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`sed -i 's/ //g' your_file` will do it, modifying the file inplace.

To delete only the whitespaces at the beginning of one single line, use `sed -i 's/^ *//' your_file`

In the first expression, we replace all spaces with nothing.
In the second one, we replace at the beginning using the `^` keyword

Comment: this script delete all whitespaces

Comment: Yes, did your question somehow mean something else?? `s/^ *//` deletes leading whitespace if that's what you want ... but perhaps you should also edit your question then.

Comment: Edited to add @tripleee comment in the answer.

Comment: The `/g` is redundant but harmless in that case, the regex already takes care of substituting all leading whitespace in one go.

Comment: Sure :-) Edited to have the simplest regexp.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'s/^\s*//'` so it removes tabs, too?

Answer (score 16):

### `tr`(delete all whitespaces):

```
$ tr -d ' ' <input.txt >output.txt
$ mv output.txt input.txt
```

### `sed`(delete leading whitespaces)

```
$ sed -i 's/^ *//' input.txt
```

Comment: and how i can change my file? The resut is wrote in console

Comment: Thank you veru much and if i want to delete only whitespace in the begin of each line of file (excuse me i edit question :( )

Comment: What about trailing whitespace?

Comment: How to **keep only** the leading white spaces?

Answer (score 4):

use can use perl -i for in place replacement.

```
perl -p -e 's/^ *//' file
```

Comment: Yes, yes! I was looking for a clean, quick way of stripping all beginning and trailing whitespace from lines in source code files. The above code strips the newline characters, not a desirable trait for my purposes, so `perl -pi -e 's/^[\ \t]+|[\ \t]+$//g' [file]` does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the white spaces before start of the line if the pattern matches. Use the following command.
For example your foo.in has pattern like this

```
      This is a test                                
                    Lolll
                       blaahhh
      This is a testtt
```

After issuing following command

```
sed -e '/This/s/ *//' < foo.in > foo.out
```

The foo.out will be

```
This is a test
             Lolll
                blaahhh
This is a testtt
```

Answer (score 1):

"***Whitespace***" can include both ***spaces*** AND ***tabs***. The solutions presented to date will only match and operate successfully on ***spaces***; they will fail if the whitespace takes the form of a ***tab***.

The below has been tested on the OP's specimen data set with both spaces AND tabs, matching successfully & operating on both:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//g' yourFile
```

After testing, supply the `-i` switch to `sed` to make the changes persistent-

Comment: i was parsing XML file and only this helped.